# Displaying Qt Licence in Thesis

Tags: licensing, license-notice

I am currently using Qt in my academic studies, and my professor wants me to display the code in the thesis.

Since all of the code will be presented in the appendix, it will become public when the thesis is published.

What's on my mind:

- Putting a header for each file that matches with the Qt license. However, this will increase the amount of paper used, as the thesis will be printed at some point.
- Putting a detailed license such as https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.12/LICENSE.LGPL3

Am I overthinking this? What is the formal way to handle this situation?

Comment: Maybe having some appendix called "attribution/s" or something, making your statements and compliance simple and to the point while still being enough correct; helps while you ponder whether to go or not go with the verbose alternative. "Am I overthinking this?" If is it deriving effort from stuff that adds value to your thesis, yes. It's just paper, make it right now, maybe improve it later.

Comment: It is normal to show *your* code in an appendix, it is not normal to show the source code of *libraries* in your thesis, unless perhaps if your thesis is about something in that code and you want to show relevant snippets. Qt consist of tens of thousands of files! Normal academic procedure would be to *cite* a specific version of the source code. You can even generate a DOI for Github repos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Putting a header for each file that matches with the Qt license. However, this will increase the amount of paper used, as the thesis will be printed at some point.

I would recommend using the [SPDX IDs](https://spdx.org/ids) of the license in a header,

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL3
```

> Putting a detailed license such as https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.12/LICENSE.LGPL3

I would then add the full license to the appendix.

Comment: SPDX IDs saved a lot of paper, and they are really expressive.